# How is affected DesiredSize by Measure?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a custom panel more responsive to design my application.

But something bother me. In my override of MeasureOverride, i call Measure on all childs of my panel.

My childs are grid like the following :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="220"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="220"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Formulaire 1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Heading1}"/>
    <Label Content="Label1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Label2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Label3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Label4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Label5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Label6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Content="Label7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Content="Label8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Content="Label9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Content="Label10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Content="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5"/>
    <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Height="85" />
</Grid>
```

This grid have a min desired width of ~407 and a max desired width of ~547. +- 140 based on min and max width of columns.

But while calling Measure on it with an available width (far) superior to the max desired width. The width of his desiredsize remains at his minimal value.

What is not expected to alter the desired size according to the available space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to inherit from grid and override MeasureOverride to take in concideration star and min/max values to calculate the desired size. My panel work better and it shouldn't have side effect (at least I didn't noticed one yet).

In my opinion, it also respond better in a wrappanel, the child will try fo fit and then after the wrappanel will try to insert the next child in the same line, else make a line break.

I don't realy understand why it's not the default behavior.

For whom interested :

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint)
    {
        //I assume Grid.MeasureOverride return the minimum size as desired size
        Size MinimumDesiredSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        //The remaining available space provided by the container
        double ConstraintWidthRemaining = constraint.Width - MinimumDesiredSize.Width;
        //The supposed remaining space if we assume than star columns width equals 0, will be calculated later
        double WidthRemaining = ConstraintWidthRemaining;
        //The width used in the remaining available space
        double WidthUsed = 0;
        //The number of column which are star sized
        double StarSum = 0;
        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in ColumnDefinitions.Where(c => c.Width.IsStar))
        {
            StarSum += column.Width.Value;
            WidthRemaining += column.MinWidth;
        }
        foreach (ColumnDefinition column in ColumnDefinitions.Where(c => c.Width.IsStar))
        {
            double Ratio = column.Width.Value / StarSum;
            double ColumnWidth = WidthRemaining * Ratio;
            if (column.MaxWidth != 0.0)
            {
                if (ColumnWidth > column.MinWidth)
                {
                    if (ColumnWidth <= column.MaxWidth)
                    {
                        WidthUsed += ColumnWidth - column.MinWidth;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WidthUsed += column.MaxWidth - column.MinWidth;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WidthUsed += ColumnWidth - column.MinWidth;
            }
        }
        MinimumDesiredSize.Width += WidthUsed;
        return MinimumDesiredSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for the two columns with a min and max width, you've specified all rows and columns as "auto". "GridLength.Auto" calculates the width (or height) according to the criteria: The minimum width (or height) that suffices to fit the content.

Therefore, calling Measure() on the grid will return a DesiredSize that's exactly enough to fit the contents of the entire grid. No more, no less. You'll have to include at least one row and column definition using "star-sizing" for it to expand to the available width that you provide.

Comment: If width isn't specified, it's set to star by default, so I have two columns which should try to fit the available space. And even if I do it, my grid keep his min width.

Comment: You're right, I was too quick with my answer. Two things however: 
1) star sizing will not ignore MaxWidth(or -Height)
2) Is it important to have the final actual size in the Measure pass? In the Arrange pas after the Measure pass, the extra space will be taken by the star sized columns, bounded by the max-width

Comment: I want to make more responsive form in my application, kinda like responsive web design, according to screen resolution (1024*768 to 1920*1200). None of WrapPanel or UniformGrid give me the behavior to fullfill my expectation.

What I expect to achieve is something which would act like a WrapPanel but responsive to dynamic size and would try to fit into available empty space. 

WrapPanel simply align chilren taking only into consideration the minimal requirement to display them and then wrap them into a new line, which mean if a child have a greater height, an ugly empty space will appear.